# I have problems installing Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: system-installation

I tried to update Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04LTS.  I have several issues and had to go back to Ubuntu 9.10.  First issue is the mouse has a drag time even when I click to speed it up. Second issue is sometimes the keyboard will freeze up and the last letter I type will repeat for about 20 times as if the key gets stuck  then the whole system freezes up and I have to reboot.  The third issue is I have DSL and the 10.04 doesn't seem to want me on the internet--In firefox I get server not found and finding software app just sits idle like it is searching for the internet.  Please help.  I love the 9.10.  I have an E-machine t5212 and 320 gb (replaced the  original 200gb after a virus shut down windows xp hard drive).  The  video card is Radeon Xpress 200.  Intel Pentium D processor and 1024mb DDR2.  I am new to Ubuntu but I have used it for about a year and love it.

Comment: I think all of the issues in one questions is not ideal here. Would it be possible to separate the issues into distinct questions?

Comment: So 9.10 works for you though? Also, did you try doing a full install of 10.04 instead of an upgrade? Upgrading tends to cause issues..

Comment: Could it be a driver issue? As in a driver that works in 9.10 but has a bug in 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

I always do a clean install... always!

**I have a few things for you though before clicking "close" or "back"**

There may be a conflicting package on your system or something causing bloat, get rid of them by typing:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Which will get rid of libs and packages which are not needed/conflicting/causing bloat.

Answer (score 1):

What about a test-drive with the Live-CD (without an installation) to check if the hardware is recognized and evey thing work well?
How did you change back to ubuntu 9.10 - i am just interested.